# JQuery selectors: Apply rule to element when certain child is NOT clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

So I have a parent div with different elements inside. Right now I have it set up so when that parent div is clicked, it applies a "selected" css attribute (just highlights it). However, there is an anchor tag inside this div and I don't want the div to highlight if the anchor is clicked.

My code to highlight the div

```
$(document).on("click",".playlist-row",function() {
        var selected = $(this);
        highlight(selected);
});
```

Ideally, I want it to behave like this: (just pseudo code)

```
$(document).on("click",".playlist-row",function() {
    var selected = $(this);
    if ($(".childElement) is not the part clicked) {
        selectSongInPlaylist(selected);
    }
});
```

Any elegant ways to get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to prevent the click event bubbling up to the container

capture the event and use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(document).on('click', "a", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You  could use stopPropogation() as in http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ on the child elements like $('.childElement').click(function(e){ 
  e.stopPropagation();
}); to prevent the click event propagating to the parent element. You could also check the event.target property as described here http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that I understood your question, so here's what I would probably do:

```
$(document).on("click", ".playlist-row", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.currentTarget).is("a")) {
        selectSongInPlaylist($(this));
    }
}
```